# Generate graphical representation of an XMI file

Tags: java, eclipse-emf, eclipse-gmf, xmi

Is there an API that can give us the possibility to generate graphical representations from a given XMI file (which is an instantiation of an Ecore file (meta-model))?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse, you can right-click, Open With->Sample Reflective Ecore Model Editor. If it's an instance model of an ecore, it should work.

Comment: Thanks for answerin , its actualy working fine for me with this way but i was asking how to do the same action but programmatically !.

Comment: For that you would need to have a graphical editor for the particular metamodel. Take a look at [GMF](http://www.eclipse.org/gmf/)